# How to perform this numerical Fourier transform?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

For $t\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $s\in\mathbb{R}$, let

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}\int_{0}^{t}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-s^{2}}\right)\,ds,&|s|<1,
\\ 0,&|s|\ge 1\end{cases}$$

I plotted this without problems using

```
Plot[NIntegrate[
Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], Abs[s] < 1}, {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}], {s, 
0, t}], {t, 0, 2}]
```

However, I am having troubles plotting $\hat{f}(\omega)$. I tried

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]

Plot[NFourierTransform[
NIntegrate[
Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], Abs[s] < 1}, {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}], {s,
0, t}], t, ω], {ω, -20, 20}]
```

without success. I can see that the problem is the `t`. However, since that is the variable I am taking the Fourier transform with respect to, I cannot arbitrarily assign it a numerical value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried sampling your $f(t)$ and then perform FFT with `Fourier`?

Comment: @BlacKow Well, I actually have a problem using the DTFT, namely `Plot[FourierSequenceTransform[
  NIntegrate[
   Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], Abs[s] < 1}, {0, Abs[s] >= 1}}], {s,
     0, n*0.1}, AccuracyGoal -> 20], {n, -20, 
   20}, \[Omega]], {\[Omega], -20, 20}]`, then `n` is not in the `FourierSequenceTransform` argument.

Comment: Why not use the integration property of the Fourier transform? If I've done the algebra right, what you want works out to be `I NFourierTransform[Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], -1 < s < 1}}], s, ω]/ω`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that can be problematic is to use functions that can deal only (or better) with numerical input values as arguments (the limits to `NIntegrate` in this example) to functions that do symbolic manipulations of their inputs (like `Plot`).
What helps most of the time is to wrap things like taking numerical integrals in a function that only evaluates if their inputs are numerical but stay unevaluated for symbolic inputs.

For your example you can e.g. try something like this:

```
f[s_?NumericQ] = Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - s^2)], -1 < s < 1}}];
fintegral[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[s], {s, 0, t},
                            AccuracyGoal -> 5,
                            Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}
                          ];
Plot[fintegral[t], {t, -2, 2}]
Needs["FourierSeries`"];
fintegralfourier[\[Omega]_?NumericQ] := NFourierTransform[fint[t], t, \[Omega],
                                          AccuracyGoal -> 5]
Off[NIntegrate::deoncon, NIntegrate::deondiv, NIntegrate::deorel]
Plot[Im@fintegralfourier[\[Omega]], {\[Omega], -20, 20}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 10, PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: f integral]

Here i used `?NumericQ` in the definition of the helper functions to let them stay unevaluated for symbolic input. This makes fintegral more safe to use as in `Plot` and `NFourierTransform`. Also i used a cheaper method as option for `NIntegrate` since we know that our integrand is very smooth and easy to integrate.

Now the next problem is, that since `NFourierTransform` internally also uses numerical integration, we do nested `NIntegrate` calls, which is very slow.

The third problem is that the function `fint` is similar to a step function, where we know that the fourier transform has a pole at zero. See for example

```
g = Piecewise[{{3 x - 4 x^3, -1/2 < x < 1/2}}, Sign[x]]
Plot[g, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: smoothstep]

where `FourierTransform` knows the exact transform result

```
gfourier=FourierTransform[Piecewise[{{3 x - 4 x^3, -1/2 < x < 1/2}}, Sign[x]], x, \[Omega]]
```

[image: gfourier formula]

which has a pole at zero:

```
Plot[Im@gfourier, {\[Omega], -10, 10}]
```

[image: gfourier plot]

So now it's understandable that `NFourierTransform` will have problems with numerical integrations near $\omega\approx 0$.